# Как сравнить ячейку гугл таблицы с текстом?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Что здесь неправильно?

```
if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange()[i][j].getValue() = text)
```

Comment: Всё ок все сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете оператор присваивания `=`,
в вашем случае нужно использовать оператор строгого сравнения `===`

> Взято с [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F): 
>   Строго равно (===)
>   Оператор возвращает истинну в том случае, если операнды строго равны. В отличие от оператора равно (==), данный оператор не приводит операнды к одному типу.

Comment: а это выражение правильно ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange()[i][j].getValue()   -   оно мне даст текст ячейки?

Comment: Это другой вопрос, вам нужно смотреть документацию

Comment: Спасибо, сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `getValue()`

```
if (
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange().getValue()
  == 
  text
){}
```

Метод `getValues()`

```
if (
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange().getValues()[i][j] 
  == 
  text
){}
```